# PHP switch strange behavoiur with zero value and strings

Tags: php, string, integer, switch-statement, zero

Going immediately to the point:

in this code I expect the ***default*** case:

```
<?php 
    $a = 0;
    switch ($a) {
        case "one":
            echo "one";
            break;
        case "two":
            echo "two";
            break;      
        default:
            echo "default";
            break;
    }
 ?>
```

I get ***one*** instead.

here expect the ***zero*** case ("*two*"):

```
 <?php 
    $a = 0;
    switch ($a) {
        case "one":
            echo "one";
            break;
        case 0:
            echo "two";
            break;      
        default:
            echo "default";
            break;
    }
 ?>
```

I get ***one*** instead.

That appens only with ***zero value*** because here I get correctly ***default***:

```
<?php 
    $a = 1;
    switch ($a) {
        case "one":
            echo "one";
            break;
        case "two":
            echo "two";
            break;      
        default:
            echo "default";
            break;
    }
 ?>
```

but here I get correctly ***zero***:

```
<?php 
    $a = 0;
    switch ($a) {
        case 1:
            echo "one";
            break;
        case 0:
            echo "zero";
            break;      
        default:
            echo "default";
            break;
    }
 ?>
```

Why?

Comment: [loose (`==`) comparison in the switch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), follows [PHP loose typed comparison rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)... so comparing integer `0` with string `"one"` is true

Comment: You gotta be careful with the types in switch statement. It doesn't work that way, you can't have an int val producing a string or a string resulting in int. I may not make sense, but the idea is to match result in an array of options. If input was int then an int output is expected and vice versa.